# Android TextView marquee

Tags: android, marquee

I'd like to shorten the text out if it's too long and add "..." at end. This is the example where I would like to clip the text:

[image]

I've tried multiple variations of code (TruncateAt.END, .setLines(4), ...) but I think this should work:

```
textv.setMaxLines(4);
textv.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
```

But the result is this:

[image]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the substring of the string, and use that as the max length, and add the ... at the end.

```
int MAX_LENGTH=40;
if(inString.length > MAX_LENGTH)
    View.setText(inString.subString(0,MAX_LENGTH) + "...";
```

I hope this will help you out...

Comment: Yes, this works. But - I thought I could get that effect using setEllipsize function?